# Ordenar un array por letra especifica

Tags: php, array, ordenamiento

He utilizado `asort` para ordenar un arreglo asociativo de palabras para un cuadro de búsqueda, opté por ello para evitar cambiar el orden de las claves, el problema es que al realizar la búsqueda la primera letra ingresada por el usuario debe aparecer entre las primeras posiciones, un ejemplo:

Aquí la búsqueda se hace comenzando por la letra ***a*** y agrega las palabras que contengan una ***a*** por orden alfabético.

[image: Orden letra A]

Aquí la búsqueda NO muestra los resultados por la primera letra (en este caso ***j***), sino que muestra el orden empezando por ***a*** y que contenga una ***j*** :

[image: Orden letra J]

### ¿Cómo podría ordenar un arreglo iniciando por una letra específica?

Aquí el código empleado:

```
# datos obtenidos por BD
$datos = array("1"=>"java","2"=>"android","3"=>"ajax","4"=>"asp.net","5"=>"javascript");
$res = array();
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];
if ($q !== "") {
    asort($datos); //ordenado por valor
    foreach($datos as $key => $value) {
        if (stristr($value,$q)) {
            if (count($res) < 5) { //limitar la busqueda a 5
                array_push($res,array('id'=>$key,'nombre'=>'#'.ucwords($value)));
            }                
        }
        
    }
}
echo count($res) === 0 ? show_404() : json_encode($res);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando ejecutas `asort` al principio del bucle, tu arreglo queda ordenado para todo lo que sigue. Lo que necesitas es reordenarlo después de haber filtrado los que calzan con el criterio. Por ejemplo puedes usar `usort` para definir tú mismo el criterio de orden:

`usort` espera una función que recibe dos elementos `$a` y `$b` y los compara de acuerdo a un criterio que tú defines. Devuelve 1 si `$a` > `$b`, 0 si son iguales y -1 si `$a` < `$b`.

En este caso tu función podría ser:

```
usort($res, function($a, $b) use ($q) {
    $pos1 = stripos($a['nombre'],$q);
    $pos2 = stripos($b['nombre'],$q);
    if($pos1 === $pos2) {
      return 0; 
    }
    return ($pos1 > $pos2) ? 1 : -1;
});
```

[(ver fiddle de ejemplo)](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ba298d853b4d8cf59f74d75824c4c1babd3065c1)

Dentro de esa función estoy diciendo: la posición de `$q` en la cadena del nombre determina si un elemento debe ir antes que el otro. Pero puedes hilar más fino y hacer que, por ejemplo, si la posición es igual en ambos elementos, ordene estos alfabéticamente.

Comment: Te agradezco, muchas gracias, me ha funcionado.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esta función te puede servir. Aquí se ordenan todos los elementos del array, empezando por la letra pasada en parámetro. Luego seguirían los demás elementos por orden alfabético.

Está contemplada también la posibilidad de letras en mayúsculas, tanto en los valores del array, como en la letra escrita que sería usada como criterio de búsqueda.

En teoría, la función hace lo siguiente:

1. Ordena alfabéticamente el array original con `natcasesort`
2. Convierte la letra pasada a minúscula usando `strtolower`, de ese modo no fallará si le pasas letras en mayúsculas.
3. Hace el mismo procedimiento con cada valor.
4. Usa `strpos` para verificar si el valor empieza con la letra pasada en parámetro. Si es así, introduce el elemento actual en un nuevo array `$arrInicial` y lo saca del array original con `unset`.
5. Al final crea un nuevo `$arrFinal`, compuesto por `$arrInicial` (donde estarán  los valores encontrados) y `$arrOrigen` (donde estarán los valores que no se encontraron).

Espero te sirva.

### Código de la función

<kbd>**[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/QZI25820)**</kbd>

```
/*Función*/
function orderArrayByChar($arrOrigen, $letra)
{
    natcasesort($arrOrigen);
    $arrInicial=array();
    $letra=strtolower($letra);

    if (count($arrOrigen) > 0) {
        foreach ($arrOrigen as $k => $v) {
            $elValor=strtolower($v);
            $siLetra = strpos($elValor, $letra) === 0;
            if ($siLetra){
                $arrInicial[$k]=$v;
                unset($arrOrigen[$k]);
            }
        }
        $arrFinal = $arrInicial+ $arrOrigen;
    }
    return $arrFinal;
}
```

### Código de prueba

```
/*Pruebas*/
echo "Array original:".PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
$arrDatos = array("1"=>"javax","2"=>"android","3"=>"ajax","4"=>"asp.net","5"=>"javascript","6"=>"phyton","7"=>"PHP");
print_r($arrDatos);

echo PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL."Prueba con j".PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
$q = 'j';//$_REQUEST["q"];
natcasesort($arrDatos);
$arrOrdenado=orderArrayByChar($arrDatos, $q);
print_r($arrOrdenado);


/*Importante usar natcasesort, si no dará problemas con las mayúsculas*/
echo PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL."Prueba con p".PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;

$q = 'P';//$_REQUEST["q"];
$arrDatos = array("1"=>"javax","2"=>"android","3"=>"ajax","4"=>"asp.net","5"=>"javascript","6"=>"phyton","7"=>"PHP");
natcasesort($arrDatos);
$arrOrdenado=orderArrayByChar($arrDatos, $q);
print_r($arrOrdenado);
```

#### Resultado:

```
Array original:

Array
(
    [1] => javax
    [2] => android
    [3] => ajax
    [4] => asp.net
    [5] => javascript
    [6] => phyton
    [7] => PHP
)


Prueba con j

Array
(
    [5] => javascript
    [1] => javax
    [3] => ajax
    [2] => android
    [4] => asp.net
    [7] => PHP
    [6] => phyton
)


Prueba con p

Array
(
    [7] => PHP
    [6] => phyton
    [3] => ajax
    [2] => android
    [4] => asp.net
    [5] => javascript
    [1] => javax
)
```